# Pyautogui randomly automatically holding shift? I guess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sublimetext, pyautogui

I'm doing mySQL for a school project where we have to manually fill a bunch of large tables so I'm using pyautogui to do it for me. I've used it on previous tables in the past and it has worked flawlessly. However when I use it now it seems almost like its holding shift at random times. At random, and not consistent, points in the output some words become capitalized, numbers and symbols go to their shift form.

```
import pyautogui as t
import time
time.sleep(5)
script = open("product.txt", "r")
for x in script:
    t.typewrite("INSERT INTO product (productName, productType, description, size, quantity, price) VALUES (")
    t.typewrite(x)
    #t.typewrite(");")
    t.press('enter')
    time.sleep(2)
```

This is my python code, just typing and reading the file

```
"lamb shank", "meat", "lamb shank in rosemary and mint sauce", "10 ounce", "20", "9.99");
"veal", "meat", "veal osso buco", "15.5 ounce", "15", "11.99");
"short rib", "meat", "braveheart angus beef boneless short rib", "12 ounce", "40", "7.99");
"flank steak", "meat", "braveheart angus beef flank steak", "2 pound", "30", "16.99");
"chicken", "meat", "boneless chicken breasts", "8 count", "56", "21.99");
"pork chops", "meat", "bacon-wrapped pork chops", "4 count", "42", "19.99");
"langoustines", "seafood", "medium wild langoustines", "7 count", "25", "20.99");
"octopus", "seafood", "cooked small octopus tentacles", "3 count", "15", "23.00");
"shrimp", "seafood", "red shrimp from argentina XL", "12 count", "50", "12.99");
"clams", "seafood", "coquina clams", "12 count", "45", "9.99");
"peas", "vegetable", "extra fine french peas", "2 pound", "60", "5.99");
"artichoke", "vegetable", "artichoke bottoms", "2 pound", "24", "17.69");
"bean", "vegetable", "very find yellow wax beans", "2 pound", "30", "6.29");
"broccoli", "vegetable", "broccoli florets", "2 pound", "55", "4.49");
"potatoes", "vegetable", "family size smashed red potatoes", "32 ounce", "55", "12.99");
"potatoes", "vegetable", "family size whipped sweet potatoes", "32 ounce", "55", "14.49");
"potatoes", "vegetable", "potatoes au gratin", "3 ounce", "55", "8.49");
"rice", "grain and rice", "jasmine rice", "2 pound", "45", "9.99");
"rice", "grain and rice", "brown", "red and wild rice medley", "2 pound", "35", "9.99");
"quinoa", "grain and rice", "organic quinoa", "2 pound", "26", "12.99");
"lentils", "grain and rice", "black beluga lentils", "2 pound 18", "9.99");
"pastry", "bakery", "frangipane king cake", "19 ounce", "32", "19.99");
"pastry", "bakery", "chocolate croissant", "3 ounce", "90", "1.90");
"dessert", "bakery", "tiramisu classico", "3 oz", "60", "4.99");
"dessert", "bakery", "authentic french creme brulee", "5 ounce", "54", "5.99");
"pie", "bakery", "cappuccino pie", "3 pound", "10", "36.50");
"cake", "bakery", "red berry cheesecake", "3 pound", "12", "36.50");
"bread", "bakery", "brioche burger buns", "4 count", "44", "4.80");
"bread", "bakery", "ciabatta sandwich 6 inch", "3 count", "28", "3.29");
"dough", "bakery", "mini blinis", "16 count", "26", "4.46");
```

This is the txt file, just completely normal comma separated strings. And then some of the outputs are as follows:

```
INSERT INTO product (productNAME< PRODUCTType, description, size, quantity, price) VALUES ("lamb shank", "meat", "lamb shank in rosemary and mint sauce", "10 ounce", "20", "9.99");

INSERT INTO product (productName, productType, description, size, quantity, price) VALUES ("lamb shank"< "meat", "lamb shank in rosemary AND MINT SAUCE", "10 ounce", "20", "9.99");
```

And like I said it is inconsistent so the weird capitalization and symbols from one run will be completely varied from the second. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use Sublime's multiple cursors to paste the beginning of the SQL statement onto every line in the file, and just execute that? Or, use the [`MySQL-python`](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/) module.

Comment: Yeah I could do those, I just use pyautogui for a lot of things so if I could resolve this issue that would be ideal.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior with other pyautogui commands? Also, are the INSERT commands actually working? If so, I personally wouldn't worry much about it.

Comment: It happens with other files, which it wasn't in the past. And the INSERT commands don't work because sometimes the commas are replaced with "<" causing errors, or data that I am trying to insert isn't inserting as intended. The weird part that I cannot seem to figure out is that sometimes the part of my python code where I type the INSERT INTO changes cases. How can that change cases if I have a String literal typed in?